# my sweet old VHS collection

Tags: video, encoding, capture, digitization, vhs

What is the best way to convert my VHS collection to something that I can view without a VHS player?

- I have a not so big collection 100 VHS
- I have plenty of storage
- I have a network media tank (A110 popcorn Hour but I can also purchase a new media center if needed)
- I have an old working VCR (but again I can pick a specific one new if you think It's better to save quality)
- The VHS cassette collection seems to have retained a good quality over the years.
  Of course I have some computer (either mac and pc) to do the process.

Which software do I need/miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to ask a professional who will do it for a cheap price. They have professional devices for this purpose so they will be able to achieve an outstanding quality (well what can they produce from a VHS). I would go with this method. (Also. 100VHS .. lets calculate with 2.5hours. .... :/)

Also what do you do if something goes FUBAR because of the old/home player ?

Comment: This would be an option for old home movies. But for anything else it's cheaper to buy a DVD.

Comment: Yeah of course. I would check which can be bought on a cheap price (and which do the questioner needs). Buy the cheap AND needed ones and digitalize the home videos with a pro.